# Inequality of weights on a graph

Tags: graph-theory, inequality

If $\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2=1$ with $x_j\!\in\!\mathbb{R}$, why does it follow that $\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^4\geq\frac{1}{n}$. I'm trying to understand the following excerpt from Brandes & Erlebach's *[Network Analysis](http://books.google.si/books?id=VIMSPCIafakC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=inverse%20participation%20ratio&f=false)*, p.[407](http://books.google.com/books?id=VIMSPCIafakC&pg=PA407#v=onepage):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By generalized mean inequality (see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality), [PlanetMath](http://planetmath.org/GeneralMeansInequality.html) or [AoPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Power_Mean_Inequality))
$$
\sqrt[4]{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^4}n} \ge \sqrt[2]{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}n}\\
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^4}n \ge \left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}n\right)^2
$$
In your case $\sum x_i^2=1$ so you have
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^4}n \ge \frac1{n^2}\\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^4 \ge \frac1{n}.$$

Comment: I was not aware of the generalized mean inequality, and the book didn't mention it anywhere. It's very simple when this inequality is known. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
1=\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2\cdot 1\leq \left( \sum_{j=1}^n (x_j^2)^2 \right)^{1/2} 
              \left( \sum_{j=1}^n 1^2 \right)^{1/2}=\left( \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^4 \right)^{1/2} n^{1/2}.
$$
Dividing by $n^{1/2}$ and squaring we obtain
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^4\geq \frac{1}{n}.
$$
We have equality if and only if $x_i=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Thanks for a different answer! CSB was all I really needed.